# How to implement amp-from tag with Google AMP

Tags: asp.net, forms, amp-html

I try to use C# with Google AMP.
As `<form>` tag is used in Asp.net, as I understand, I have to use the `<amp-form>` tag in Google AMP. But it gets error.

I have this code

```
<body>
  <amp-form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </amp-form>
</body>
```

The error in hint

```
Validation (HTML5): Element 'amp-form' is not supported.
```

How can I fix this?
Is it possible to use ASP.Net C# with Google AMP ?
Thanks

Comment: This page describes amp-form but the custom-element in that page is also undefined in my Asp.Net project. https://amp.dev/tr/documentation/components/amp-form/

Comment: I do not understand why you think anyone might be able to help here based on the information supplied. With your rep you should know how to work on the site.

Comment: @Jay Gray form tag is used in Asp.net, and as I understand, I have to use the amp-form Tag. But it gets error. How can I fix it? I say this.

Comment: @Jay Gray Thanks, I have corrected my question

Comment: I think JS is the only language supported in `<amp-script>`. Server-side processing is much more flexible, However, I'm not aware of anyone using C# server-side to communicate with a form. We do a lot of server-side but use typescript. IMHO your best path here is to use express templates with JS. Forms, autosuggest, et al become much easier to implement.

Comment: @Jay Gray, form tags are always be in ASP.net pages. Do you say, can’t I use ASP.net with Google AMP?

Comment: I wanted Google AMP for the speed, but maybe its better for me to use CDN for ASP.net.